# Journals for credit with suppliers

Tags: small-business, insurance, accounting, car-insurance, sole-proprietorship

How would I keep a record of payments with an insurance supplier (Zego if that helps) if they bill on the basis that the account gets topped up with credit, then they deduct from the credit on a pay as you go basis?

I.e: Top up so you have £100 credit, they then deduct £x here and there when the vehicle is used, then when the credit falls below £5 you would top up again.

*To further clarify this is for working with Deliveroo/UberEats in the UK among others, on a sole proprietor basis*

Comment: Is this a personal finance question or an accounting question?

Comment: Hi; welcome to the site.  Business accounting is not on topic here, unfortunately (only personal accounting).  Given your tags, it looks like this is asking about business accounting, so I'm voting to close the question.  You may want to find a site that specializes in business accounting (or, better yet, hire an accountant).

Comment: In the US, at least, it's considered an asset in the `Prepaid Expenses` class which is countered by a reduction in `Cash`.  Each time a chunk of that prepaid expense is used, it is countered by an `Expense` entry.

Comment: @Joe sole proprietorship bookkeeping is explicitly on-topic.  https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RonJohn If this is a SP, then that's fine - but that's not evident at the moment.  That's more of an exception than really the point of this site, so it's not an assumption I make by default (nor should you).

Comment: @Joe and there's no evidence that it's **not* an SP.  All we know in the `small-business` tag.

Comment: @RonJohn That's certainly true, but the expectation on Stack Exchange sites is that questions have all of the information necessary to answer them - including whether they are on topic - and so the default should be to close (with information to the OP of course as to how to ensure it's on topic).

Comment: For Dave Smith - I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're a Uber/Lyft/Grubhub/etc. contractor.  If that's the case, then just add that information to the question - and then you're good to go and this will definitely be considered on topic here.  The way you asked the question that's not clear.

Comment: @Joe I've seen not only way too many questions, but way too many which I think are obviously off-topic and yet no one else voted to close because they considered them acceptably on-top because of ambiguity and "close enough" for your comment about expectations on Money.SE to be valid.  TL;DR: I think you're wrong.

Comment: @Joe If the question would be on-topic if it includes the magic sentence “I am an Uber worker,” and has no other changes, then it is on-topic period. The motivations of a question asker are irrelevant as to whether or not the question is on-topic. If this question would be on-topic if *somebody* asked it, then it is on-topic if *anybody* asks it. We don’t discriminate here.

Comment: @DaveSmith That having been said, you will likely get a much better answer if you include more details about what exactly it is you want to do and why.

Comment: @Joe see update to question - this is for a sole proprietorship

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to keep a loan account (in your accounting package) in the name of the supplier. Put the account in an Asset or Liability register (check with your accountant which they prefer) so that it isn’t treated as an expense account.

When you send money to the supplier, you record it as going from your bank account to the loan account.

When you incur a usage fee, you record it as a payment coming out of the loan account.

By creating the account in an Asset or Liability register, you are effectively treating the account like a bank account. The accounting package should therefore consider the balance of your loan account as part of your net worth. Funds are treated as expenses only when you record your usage fees.